# Forwarding MySQL localhost to remote server

Tags: php, mysql, ssh-tunnel

I am in the process of moving from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.

I have a virtual machine running PHP 5.6 (PHP5) with MySQL running on it. The code is mounted from my host.

I have a second virtual machine running PHP 7 (PHP7). The code is also mounted from my host. All of my projects are configured with "localhost" as the database host.

As the first step, I want to have the MySQL "localhost" on PHP7 go directly to the PHP5 MySQL instance.

I have setup an ssh tunnel such that port 3306 on PHP7 goes directly to 3306 on PHP5, but this doesn't seem to help (EDIT: although if I change the config in a project to have a 127.0.0.1:3306 host it does work, but the host change is what I'm wondering whether I can avoid :) ).

Is there a way to setup the forwarding so that the projects will just work (or not), or do I need to go through each project and update it to cope with both servers?

Comment: You seem to have chosen a very complicated way of doing this. When you say this code is mounted from my host do you mean you use docker?

Comment: I am using VirtualBox, it is mounted as a vboxsf into the PHP5 (Ubuntu 14) and PHP7 (Ubuntu 16) installations.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you had a third VM with *just* MySQL on it and had the other two connect to that. Forget "localhost", instead use the private IP of that instance. Using SSH locally is very messy compared to using private networking. You can set up multiple machines in VirtualBox very easily with [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com) by the way, and it can handle routine stuff like port forwarding or IP assignment.

Comment: so why have you put mysql inside that virtualbox? for this sort of thing virtualbox is way overkill. Better to use docker or in your case the simple matter of putting mysql on the bare metal would make life a lot easier

Comment: There are various reasons that I have it this way, but what it comes down to is that I like to replicate the real servers and this is the easiest way for me. I can update the projects configs and it will work, I'm just wondering if there's a trick I can use to make the new server proxy the MySQL localhost connection to the development database.